# Could not start ocamlbrowser on Windows

Tags: ocaml

Problem: ocamlbrowser could not be started on Windows 8.

When I was installing ocaml on windows, it complained that the Tcl package could not be downloaded. I downloaded ActiveState ActiveTcl8.5.13 manually; however, ocamlbrowser still failed to start. I don't know if there's anything wrong with my installation, or configuration. In my point of view, ocamlbrowser is an useful tool, especially for beginner. Could someone help me to figure this out?

OS:    Windows 8, 64-bit.
Ocaml:    4.00.1 (installed using official windows binary installer)
Tcl:    ActiveTcl8.5.13 (installed after ocaml installation.)

Thanks!
Nick

Comment: I recommend you to use VMWare or VirtualBox + Linux to play with OCaml in your windows box. OCaml in Windows is only for who can handle those problems by themselves.

Comment: Thank you, camlspotter! It might be true that Windows is not the OS on which OCaml is widely used. Actually there's a similar implementation, F# and VisualStudio support on Windows. But I prefer OCaml's efficiency and concise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install a 32bit version of Active Tcl ("x86"), you installed 64bit while ocamlbrowser from that installer is linked against a 32bit one.

Try this dependency browser to see for yourself. http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: I installed 32-bit ActiveTcl, and successfully started ocamlbrowser. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Nick np, but do consider moving to linux for any serious Ocaml work.